# Filter expired cards from array React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

I have a following twisted situation and need some guidance. Here is the code

This below function is to test whether the credit card is expired or not. This function returns a boolean `true` if card is expired and `false` is card is valid

```
const isCardExpired = (mm, yy) => {
  const month = parseInt(mm, 10);
  const year = parseInt(yy, 10);
  const date = new Date();
  const currentYear = parseInt(
    date
      .getFullYear()
      .toString()
      .substr(-2),
    10
  );
  const currentMonth = date.getMonth() + 1;
  console.log(month, year, date, currentYear, currentMonth);
  if (year < currentYear) {
    return true;
  }

  if (month > 12 || (year === currentYear && month < currentMonth)) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

And here is my `PaymentMethods` array of length `3`. It can vary and thats why i have to loop it through.

```
(3) [PaymentMethod, PaymentMethod, PaymentMethod]
0: PaymentMethod
data:
    cardLast4Digits: "1111"
    cardType: "CREDIT"
    expiryMonth: "2"
    expiryYear: "19"

1: PaymentMethod
data:
    cardLast4Digits: "6144"
    cardType: "DEBIT"
    expiryMonth: "12"
    expiryYear: "24
2: PaymentMethod
data:
    cardLast4Digits: "6949"
    cardType: "VISA"
    expiryMonth: "12"
    expiryYear: "25"
length: 3
```

Here is what i need to do, I need to loop through all the 3 payment methods and only pick up `cardType: "CREDIT` and check if card is expired with above `isCardExpired` function. `yy` and `mm` to this function is basically `expiryMonth` and `expiryYear` from `PaymentMethods`

Once it finds `cardType: CREDIT`, it will check if card is expired, If it is expired, it will remove that payment method from `paymentMethods` array and assign it to a different array.

for e.g, if there are 2 expired credit cards, it should be removed from `PaymentMethods` array and push it to a different array which will list these 2 expired credit cards.

Can someone please shed some light on this difficulty.

Comment: You'll want to filter the invalid payments from the paymentMethods array and push them into the new array. As long as you're passing that object to React or handling this through React state, it will internally recognize a change in state and re-render. On array filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const expiredCards = paymentMethods.filter(c => c.data.cardType === "CREDIT" && isCardExpired(c.data.expiryMonth, c.data.expiryYear));
paymentMethods= paymentMethods.filter(c => c.data.cardType !== "CREDIT" || !isCardExpired(c.data.expiryMonth, c.data.expiryYear));
```

Comment: this has confused me further. i only wanted to loop through regular array and get expired ones out of it. dont need to use props or anything

Comment: @oemera- it gives `expiredCards` but does it remove the expired ones from the original  `PaymentMethods` array

Comment: No `allCards` will be untouched. It will have all cards still, valid and expired ones. Try `console.log(allCards)` after the filter.

Comment: @oemera- i actually want allCards to contact only valid ones once we seperate out expiredCards as mentioned above

Comment: Updated my post once more :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203201/discussion-between-oemera-and-user3019647).

Comment: allCards an array of allCard instances (all the code inside of the allCards is always working with instances of allCard)? If so, then c.cardType doesn't exist. i am not able to get expiredCards with your code.

Comment: I renamed `allCards` to `paymentMethods` to make it more clear. After you apply my code, you should have all expired cards in `expiredCards` and all valid cards in the original `paymentMethods` array.

Comment: const expiredCards = paymentMethods.filter(c => c.data.cardType === "CREDIT" && isCardExpired(c.data.expiryMonth, c.data.expiryYear));


Can you update your answer with this working one. i have accepted your answer

Comment: You are right. I missed the `data` part. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood correctly what you want to achieve but here is my example

```
const getExpiredCards = (paymentMethods)=>paymentMethods.filter(({expiryMonth,expiryYear,cardType})=>cardType === 'CREDIT' && isCardExpired(expiryMonth,expiryYear))
```

Comment: I need to put expired credit cards in one array and want all valid ones in the original array `paymentMethods`

Comment: something like that or do you want to store it in one object like in the previous version of my answer?

Comment: is there a way to delete expired ones from the original array `PaymentMethods`

Comment: if you want to use it after that as prop of any component it is not possible. You should create a new "container" to store values.

Answer (score 1):

Using ES6, the spead operator, and reduce:

```
function partitionExpiredCards(cardArray) {
 return cardArray.reduce(
  ([pass, fail], elem) => {
   return isCardExpired(elem) ? [[...pass, elem], fail] : [pass, [...fail, elem]];
  },
  [[], []]
 );
}

const [ExpiredPaymentMethods, ValidPaymentMethods] = partition(PaymentMethods);
```

Which can be alternatively written:

```
const [ExpiredPaymentMethods, ValidPaymentMethods] = PaymentMethods.reduce(([p, f], v) => (isCardExpired(v) ? [[...p, v], f] : [p, [...v, e]]), [[], []]);
```

---

For either example, if *PaymentMethods* should not be mutated, replace *PaymentMethods* with:

```
[...PaymentMethods]
```